# Can I Use different menu for mobile in responsive website? for SEO point of view and loading time

Tags: menu, responsive

I am developing a website which req different menu style for mobile. Can I create 2 menu, one for desktop and other for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

try bootstrap framework that will handle both and you want to make changes create custom.js and write your custom style in it